# Find equation of tangential plane at a given point of a surface

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, conic-sections, parametric, tangent-spaces

I have a parametric, regular surface 
$$s(u,v)=(\cosh(u)\cos(v),\cosh(u)\sin(v),\sinh(u)),$$ 
$(u,v)\in\mathbb{R}^2$. I need to find tangent plane in point $Q=s(1,0)$. I used the formula for calculation the plane but the problem is I can't get an explicit equation.

I got $$(x, y, z) = (\cosh(1)+u\sinh(1)-\sinh(1),v\cosh(1), \sinh(1)+u\cosh(1)-\cosh(1)).$$

Have I missed something or is there a better way. I know that this surface is a surface of one sheet hyperboloid but I can't use the standard formula.

Comment: You clearly made some error along the way since $u$ and $v$ shouldn’t appear anywhere in the solution. Show more details of your work if you’d like someone to explain just what that error was. What formula exactly did you use? How did you apply it?

Comment: Firstly I've calculated the derivatives: $$s_u = (\cos(v)\sinh(u), \sin(v)\sinh(u), \cosh(u))$$ and $$s_v = (-\cosh(u)\sin(v), \cosh(u)\cos(v), 0)$$, then calculated for (1,0) and got: $$s_u(1,0) = (\sinh(1), 0, \cosh(1))$$ and $$s_v(1,0) = (0, \cosh(1), 0)$$. And of course $s(1,0) = (\cosh(1), 0, sinh(1))$, and then I tried to use formula: $$(x,y,z) = s(u_0,v_o) + s_u(u_0,v_0)(u-u_0)+s_v(u_0,v_0)(v-v_0)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were doing fine until the last step, when you used a template for a parametric equation of the tangent plane, i.e., a linear approximation to $s$ at $(1,0)$. To get an implicit Cartesian equation, you can either eliminate $u$ and $v$ from the result (note that they’re *not* the same $u$ and $v$ as in the parameterization of the surface), or use the point-normal form of plane equation in the first place. To do the latter, you need a normal vector to the surface at $s(1,0)$, which is just $s_u(1,0)\times s_v(1,0) = (-\cosh^2(1),0,\cosh(1)\sinh(1))$, which you can divide by $-\cosh(1)$ to keep the expressions simpler. The implicit equation of the tangent plane at $s(1,0)$ is then $\mathbf n\cdot\mathbf x = \mathbf n\cdot s(1,0)$, or $$x\cosh(1)-y\sinh(1)=\cosh^2(1)-\sinh^2(1) = 1.$$

Answer (score 1):

Write the surface as

$$x^2+y^2-z^2=1$$

and the point $s(1,0)$ corresponds to $\vec{Q} = (\cosh(1),0,\sinh(1))$. The vector normal to the surface at the point $(x,y,z)$ is given by $(z_x',z_y',-1$), or

$$\vec{n} = (\coth(1),0,-1)$$

Let $\vec{P}=(x,y,z)$ be the points on the tangent plane, which has to satisfy $\vec{n}\cdot\vec{QP}=0$, or,

$$(\coth(1),0,-1)\cdot(x-\cosh(1),y,z-\sinh(1))=0$$

Thus, the equation of the tangent plane is

$$\cosh(1)x-\sinh(1)z=1$$

Comment: Thank you! I have a question, how did you come to $n  = (\coth(1), 0, -1)$?

Comment: @variableXYZ - the normal vector $\vec{n}$ is evaluated according to $(z_x',z_y',-1)$